# finding odd or even from a array and inserting the value in to desired array. Not getting desired output

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
    public class Arr1{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        int a[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
        int even[]=new int[a.length];
        int odd[]=new int[a.length]; 
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            if(a[i]%2==0){
                for(int j=0;j<even.length;j++){
                    even[j]=a[i];
                }
            }else{
                for(int z=0;z<odd.length;z++){
                    odd[z]=a[i];
                }
            }
        }
        for(int j=0;j<even.length;j++){
            System.out.print(even[j]+" ");          
        }System.out.println();
        for(int z=0;z<odd.length;z++){
            System.out.print(odd[z]+" ");
        }    
    }
}
```

output:

```
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 
19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19 19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `even[j]=a[i];` and `odd[z]=a[i];` in loop is causing last odd `19` and even `20` values to overwrite all other values.

I have added an if condition to check `even[j]` or `odd[z]` is 0, then only assign the value as default value of int array item would be 0.

Here is the complete code:

```java
public class Arr1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
        int even[] = new int[a.length];
        int odd[] = new int[a.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] % 2 == 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < even.length; j++) {
                    // Added if condition here
                    if (even[j] == 0) {
                        even[j] = a[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for (int z = 0; z < odd.length; z++) {
                    // Added if condition here
                    if (odd[z] == 0) {
                        odd[z] = a[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < even.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(even[j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int z = 0; z < odd.length; z++) {
            System.out.print(odd[z] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

> 1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Output has 0s because `odd` and `even` array size is equal to size of input array and values not assigned in odd and even arrays would have default value of 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simplified version, which is not using inner `for`-loops:

```
int evenIndex = 0, oddIndex = 0;
int[] even = new int[a.length], odd = new int[a.length];
for (int i : a) {
    if ((i & 1) == 1) {
        odd[oddIndex++] = i;
    } else {
        even[evenIndex++] = i;
    }
}
```

If you want to "cut" the resulting arrays to their actual size you can use the following:

```
even = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(even, 0, evenIndex);
odd = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(odd, 0, oddIndex);
```

And if you don't want to or somehow can't use `java.util.Arrays` then you can achieve the same by using the following:

```
// create array of size == actual element count
int[] evenCutToSize = new int[evenIndex];
// copy elements one by one
for (int i = 0; i < evenIndex; i++) {
    evenCutToSize[i] = even[i];
}
```

Comment: can you explain why are you, initilizing the evenindex and oddindex outside ?

Comment: @sujoy98 the `evenIndex` and `oddIndex` are used to know where we have to insert the new element (`i`) into the `even` or `odd` array, that way we don't have to loop through the (even or odd) array to know where we have to insert the new element, like in the other answer

Comment: ThankYou so much, may one day I could code like you :(